# How to let google crawl pdf files but not index them?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

if i understand it right, you can only tell google to crawl or not crawl pdf files via robots.txt. i want google to crawl the files, but not list them in the search results pages.

is this possible?

Comment: Ok, so what would google do with the information? Google: ah! here's a Pdf file. Nice .. but ... what do u want me to do with this? I provide search results .. and u're asking me to NOT list this file in any search results... er.....

Comment: @Pure.Krome: if its a pay for download resource it is a valid move. Otherwise google could cache it.

Comment: That means Google should index the PDF (i.e. return it in the list of results) but not make the contents available from the Google cache?

Answer (score 2):

You can add robots directives to any file via the x-robots-tag http header. Setting it to noindex, follow sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but isnt this: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` a good solution for your problem.?

Comment: sure i meant the link to the pdf file in the html.